# Calculating the similarity of two lists

Tags: python, algorithm

I have two lists:

eg.
a = [1,8,3,9,4,9,3,8,1,2,3]
and
b = [1,8,1,3,9,4,9,3,8,1,2,3]

Both contain ints. There is no meaning behind the ints (eg. 1 is not 'closer' to 3 than it is to 8).

I'm trying to devise an algorithm to calculate the similarity between two ORDERED lists. Ordered is keyword right here (so I can't just take the set of both lists and calculate their set_difference percentage). Sometimes numbers do repeat (for example 3, 8, and 9 above, and I cannot ignore the repeats).

In the example above, the function I would call would tell me that a and b are ~90% similar for example. How can I do that? Edit distance was something which came to mind. I know how to use it with strings but I'm not sure how to use it with a list of ints. Thanks!

Comment: Considering a string to simply be a list of characters, there would seem to be a pretty simple mapping between calculating edit distance on strings and calculating edit distance on lists of integers.

Comment: maybe you are looking for the [hamming distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance)?

Comment: @Pat B: Hamming distance requires the sequences to be of the same length, and it can't deal with deletions/insertions. Take a look at the OP's example (`a` and `b`).

Comment: @aix: good point. You could zip down the two lists with izip_longest to solve that problem I guess.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can use the [difflib](http://docs.python.org/library/difflib.html) module

> ratio()
>   Return a measure of the sequences’ similarity as a float in the range [0, 1].

Which gives :

```
 >>> s1=[1,8,3,9,4,9,3,8,1,2,3]
 >>> s2=[1,8,1,3,9,4,9,3,8,1,2,3]
 >>> sm=difflib.SequenceMatcher(None,s1,s2)
 >>> sm.ratio()
 0.9565217391304348
```

Comment: only problem here would be those spaces also end up counting in the percent difference

Comment: More reason why you don't want to use this approach: this punishes double-digit integers more than single digit ones and can sometimes confuse single and double (or more) digit numbers.

Comment: in fact no (about the spaces) because the SequenceMatcher is smart enough to detect spaces as junk.

Comment: @aerain after checking the doc, SequenceMatcher accept sequences of any type, so I edited the answer to process int lists

Comment: thanks! Ignore my previous comments in this thread now. I actually like this approach the best!

Comment: This is incredibly useful, I was trying to find similarity between word arrays and it works like a charm

Comment: Thanks, but it does not work for all cases. For instance, with s1=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] and  s2=[2,1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,9] it returns 0.8 instead of 0.7 (there are 3 elements which are different)

Answer (score 12):

It sounds like edit (or Levenshtein) distance is precisely the right tool for the job.

Here is one Python implementation that can be used on lists of integers: http://hetland.org/coding/python/levenshtein.py

Using that code, `levenshtein([1,8,3,9,4,9,3,8,1,2,3], [1,8,1,3,9,4,9,3,8,1,2,3])` returns `1`, which is the edit distance.

Given the edit distance and the lengths of the two arrays, computing a "percentage similarity" metric should be pretty trivial.

Comment: Yup works great. Thanks! What would you divide the edit distance by to get the percent? Not sure which one of the lists to use

Comment: actually I'd recommend the difflib module approach. I didn't know it could be used to compare sequence similarity.

Comment: To get a ratio, you could divide by the length of the sequences!

Answer (score 5):

One way to tackle this is to utilize [histogram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram). As an example (demonstration with [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/)):

```
In []: a= array([1,8,3,9,4,9,3,8,1,2,3])
In []: b= array([1,8,1,3,9,4,9,3,8,1,2,3])

In []: a_c, _= histogram(a, arange(9)+ 1)
In []: a_c
Out[]: array([2, 1, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 4])

In []: b_c, _= histogram(b, arange(9)+ 1)
In []: b_c
Out[]: array([3, 1, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 4])

In []: (a_c- b_c).sum()
Out[]: -1
```

There exist now plethora of ways to harness `a_c` and `b_c`.

Where the (seemingly) simplest similarity measure is:

```
In []: 1- abs(-1/ 9.)
Out[]: 0.8888888888888888
```

Followed by:

```
In []: norm(a_c)/ norm(b_c)
Out[]: 0.92796072713833688
```

and:

```
In []: a_n= (a_c/ norm(a_c))[:, None]
In []: 1- norm(b_c- dot(dot(a_n, a_n.T), b_c))/ norm(b_c)
Out[]: 0.84445724579043624
```

Thus, you need to be much more specific to find out most suitable similarity measure suitable for your purposes.

Comment: I know its been ages, but can you reference similarity measures you gave?

Answer (score 3):

Just use the same algorithm for calculating edit distance on strings if the values don't have any particular meaning.

Answer (score 1):

I've implemented something for a similar task a long time ago. Now, I have only [a blog entry for that](http://pgraycode.wordpress.com/2009/09/21/uniformity/). It was simple: you had to compute the pdf of both sequences then it would find the common area covered by the graphical representation of pdf.

Sorry for the broken images on link, the external server that I've used back then is dead now.

Right now, for your problem the code translates to

```
def overlap(pdf1, pdf2):
    s = 0
    for k in pdf1:
        if pdf2.has_key(k):
            s += min(pdf1[k], pdf2[k])
    return s

def pdf(l):
    d = {}
    s = 0.0
    for i in l:
        s += i
        if d.has_key(i):
            d[i] += 1
        else:
            d[i] = 1
    for k in d:
        d[k] /= s
    return d

def solve():
    a = [1, 8, 3, 9, 4, 9, 3, 8, 1, 2, 3]
    b = [1, 8, 1, 3, 9, 4, 9, 3, 8, 1, 2, 3]
    pdf_a = pdf(a)
    pdf_b = pdf(b)
    print pdf_a
    print pdf_b
    print overlap(pdf_a, pdf_b)
    print overlap(pdf_b, pdf_a)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    solve()
```

Unfortunately, it gives an unexpected answer, only `0.212292609351`

Answer (score 1):

The solution proposed by @kraymer does not work in the case of

```
s1=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
s2=[2,1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,9]
```

since it returns 0.8 even though there are 3 different elements and not 2.

A workaround could be:

```
def find_percentage_agreement(s1, s2):
    assert len(s1)==len(s2), "Lists must have the same shape"
    nb_agreements = 0  # initialize counter to 0
    for idx, value in enumerate(s1):
        if s2[idx] == value:
            nb_agreements += 1

    percentage_agreement = nb_agreements/len(s1)

    return percentage_agreement
```

Which returns the expected result:

```
>>> s1=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
>>> s2=[2,1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,9]
>>> find_percentage_agreement(s1, s2)
0.7
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless im missing the point.

```
from __future__ import division

def similar(x,y):
    si = 0
    for a,b in zip(x, y):
        if a == b:
            si += 1
    return (si/len(x)) * 100


if __name__ in '__main__':
    a = [1,8,3,9,4,9,3,8,1,2,3] 
    b = [1,8,1,3,9,4,9,3,8,1,2,3]
    result = similar(a,b)
    if result is not None:
        print "%s%s Similar!" % (result,'%')
```

Comment: I think the main issue is that it can't deal with deletions/insertions (it considers the two sequences in this OP's example as 18% similar whereas he is expecting ~90%).