# Put keys from dictionary to new list based on other lists

Tags: python

I am a total beginner on python and wondering if this is possible?

```
businessideas = {
"DeliDelivery": ['bread'],
"Ikea": ['sofa','table'],
'Volvo': ['car','window'],
'saab' : ['window']
}




carkeywords = ['car', 'engine']
furniturekeywords = ['sofa', 'bookshell']
bakerykeywords = ['bread', 'flour', 'cookies']

carkeywords_competitors = []
furniturekeywords_competitors = []
bakerykeywords_competitors = []
```

I want to create a function that puts every dictionary-key in a competitors list if they have a common value. So for an example the key Ikea has the elements sofa and table. Then the function should see that the value sofa is a duplicate to of furniturekeywords elements. Then the funtion should put the key Ikea in the list furniturekeywords_competitors. If it would have the same value as carkeywords the function would have put the key in carkeywords_competitors.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Yes, this is possible.  However, your *actual* problem is not clear.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.

Comment: [Calculating the similarity of two lists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6709693/calculating-the-similarity-of-two-lists)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I compare two lists in python and return matches](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388818/how-can-i-compare-two-lists-in-python-and-return-matches)

Answer (score 2):

So the task is to find those sets of items that are not disjoint with the keywords. This can be done with `set`s and the [`isdisjoint`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set.isdisjoint) method:

```
businessideas = {
"DeliDelivery": ['bread'],
"Ikea": ['sofa','table'],
'Volvo': ['car','window'],
'saab' : ['window']
}

carkeywords = ['car', 'engine']

def competitors(ideas, keywords):
   keywords = set(keywords)
   return [k for k,v in ideas.items() 
           if not keywords.isdisjoint(v)]

carkeywords_competitors = competitors(businessideas, carkeywords)
```

results in:

```
>>> carkeywords_competitors
['Volvo']
```

---

Note that if the elements of the lists weren't hashable, but did have equality defined for them, `any(i in kwds for i in v)` would be what I would use. (if they didn't have equality the task would be impossible and the only option would be `False`) But they are hashable as they are strings. So `not set(v).isdisjoint(kwds)` beats that.